# Динамический и статический вызов библиотеки

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dll

Какие есть нюансы и отличия в загрузке библиотеки динамически и получения ее функций(GetProcAddress), и подключение ее непосредственно в студии с .lib и .h?

Во втором случае, при сборке с помощью GCC я не получаю .lib(можно вручную получить), к тому же не выносил прототипы методов в header вида

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void NumberList();
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void LetterList();
```

Comment: А есть же еще вариант с вообще пустыми импортами и получением адресов через TEB/PIB. Но за такое по рукам бить надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница, разумеется, в контроле компилятора.

В случае с линковкой через `.h` вы просто берёте и пользуетесь функцией. Точно так же, как вы пользуетесь функцией `printf`. Просто, беспроблемно, всё сделано за вас и работает из коробки. Усилия минимальны.

В случае с динамической работой с библиотекаой вам нужно всё делать вручную с возможностью ошибиться: проверить путь к библиотеке, загрузить её, позаботиться о том, когда вы будете её выгружать, не перепутать строку в именем функции, сигнатуру функции, вызывать нужно не прямо, а через указатель и т. п.

Плюс от динамической работы — вам не нужно наличие библиотеки во время компиляции проекта. Вы можете (или пользователь вашей программы может) принести её потом, и «скормить» вашей программе. (Таким образом, например, можно организовать плагинную систему.) Вы можете выгрузить её и подменить на другую. Да ваша программа может даже просто сдампить .c-файл, скомпилировать его системным компилятором и подключить!

Comment: Кроме статики и ручного LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress есть динамическая загрузка через импорты. Код будет в DLL, но просто берете и пользуетесь функцией: линкер добавляет информацию о DLL в импорты и ее загрузка происходит при загрузке образа в память.
PS а есть еще гнусное извращение: lib содержит только код для LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress и стабы для вызова функций из DLL. В итоге вроде статика, в импортах ничего, но все равно DLL нужна...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Ну, это да, но это всё же вариант статической компоновки, на этапе компиляции, а не после неё.

Comment: Я бы не стал это статикой называть: код в другом образе и без него работать не будет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Ну, назовите программой совокупность двух файлов. Вопрос определения. Если вы при полностью статической линковке тоже вырежете библиотеку из файла, то тоже не будет работать. В любом случае, разница при работе через LoadLibrary намного больше.

Comment: Вот хотел бы я уметь вырезать из готового EXE то, что в него подключалось из LIB... Да для произвольного компилятора и линкера :-(

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Да, с нестатической линковкой это удобнее :)

Comment: Тоже не всегда: самописный GetProcAddress через парсинг экспортов и получение адреса не по имени, а по хэшу встречал не раз :-( Но за такое тоже по рукам.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Мне, слава богу, не встречалось такое, у меня психика к такому не готова :)